# find the minimum and maximum distance between 2 rectangles of any dimension

Tags: java, geometry

I have a Rectangle class that represents a  d-dimension rectangle with 2*d numbers for every dimension. For every dimension i have a lower and an upper bound. Dimensionality stores the number of dimensions of the rectangle, and for the lower and upper bounds i use a double array.

I want to create 2 methods that they have as input another rectangle object of the same Dimensionality and return the minimum and maximum distance between the rectangles, im trying to do this using the minimum/maximum distances of each of their projections in every axis. I also have a method that creates the projections.

```
//returns 2 position array
    public double[] project(int x)
    {
        //x is the selected dimension
        double proj[] = new double[2];
        proj[0] = this.lb[x];
        proj[1] = this.ub[x];
        return proj;
    }
```

you can see on the third set of shapes what i want to do more clearly

https://s15.postimg.org/l8aijyl1n/imageedit_2_6689786765.jpg

Comment: why do you calculate the distance of the projections? How does it help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Find mutual orientation of rectangles (as direction of vector between centers, it is enough to get signs of center.x and center.y differences)
2. Depending on orientation quadrant, get distances from selected edges of the first rectangle to selected edges of the second. Using signs of these distances, find extremal distances:

For the case at the picture (direction in the 4th quadrant) one have to check distances from right bottom corner of the first rectangle to the left and top edges of the second one, and from left top corner of the second - to the right and bottom edges of the first one.

```
 min_dx = rect2.left - rect1.right
 min_dy = rect2.top - rect.bottom
 if both values > 0 (++ case)
    min_dist = sqrt(min_dx^2 + min_dy^2) //corner-corner case

 +- case
   min_dist = min_dx
 -+ case
   min_dist = min_dy
 -- case
    min_dist = 0
```

Seems the same approach might be used for higher dimensions. Number of cases becomes too high, so it is worth to select planes for checking with indexes corresponding to center-center direction vector components' signs

Comment: yeap this is what i came up for a 2-dimension rectangle, what about d-dimension rects? any ideas on this?

Comment: Some thoughts added